# how do I format mathematical operators to str

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

This is my problem:

I want to achieve the following output with changing values of x and z in a while loop:

```
x * z = 1 (=x*z)
```

That's what I got so far:

```
str(x)*str(y)= 1
```

How do I convert "*" and "=" to a string? str() is not working... Also, I cannot put everything under "..." as the values of str(x) and str(y) wont change this way.

Thank you

Edit:

Maybe I am a bit unclear.

> ```
> x = 1
> z=0
> while z  < n:
>     z = z +1
>     print "str(x)*str(y)=",x*z
> ```

This part "str(x)*str(y)=" should print as text, but I cannot put everything in brackets as the values of x and y wont change this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. `*` and `=` are not objects, they are operators, part of the language.

Just use strings for those.

```
print '{} * {} = 1'.format(x, y)
```

uses [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) to interpolate `x` and `y` into a string; note the `*` and `=` are already part of the string.

Comment: thanks. where can I read about this method? is {} a placeholder in combination with .format?

Comment: @aaaa: apologies, I meant to link to the documentation for `.format()`. Done now. Yes, `{}` is a simple placeholder, more complex value selection and formatting options are available.